# Mapeo de xml a Objetos Java - Null Pointer in Class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Estoy tratando de mapear un xml a clases Java. Resulta que me llega de entrada un xml, y necesito desglosarlo en clases.

INPUT XML:

```
<empleado>
  <nombre>juan</nombre>
  <segundo_nombre>pablo</segundo_nombre>
  <apellido>perez</apellido>
  <dni>9999</dni>
  <calle>San martin</calle>
  <numero_calle>123</numero_calle>
  <piso>4r</piso>
</empleado>
```

Necesito que los tag  y  esten en otra clase. Yo lo mappee de la siguiente manera:

CLASE EMPLEADO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "empleado")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Empleado implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "nombre", required = true)
    private String nombre;
    @XmlElement(name = "segundo_nombre", required = true)
    private String segundo_nombre;
    @XmlElement(name = "dni", required = true)
    private String dni;
    private Direccion direccion = new Direccion();
```

CLASE DIRECCION:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "empleado")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Direccion implements Serializable {
    private String calle;
    private String numero_calle;
    private String piso;
```

Ambas con sus setters y getters.

Al hacer el Unmarshall

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        //getting the xml file to read
        File file = new File("\Empleado.xml");
        System.out.println("{} processing fileName='{}'" + file);

        //creating the JAXB context
        JAXBContext jContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Direccion.class, Empleado.class);
        //creating the unmarshall object
        unmarshaller = jContext.createUnmarshaller();
        //calling the unmarshall method
        Empleado emp = (Empleado) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(emp.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Me devuelve:

```
> Empleado{nombre=juan, segundo_nombre=pablo, dni=9999,
> direccion=Direccion{calle=null, numero_calle=null, piso=null}}
```

No me esta tomando los datos de la clase direccion. Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando? o de que otra forma puede represnetar esto?

Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que la anotación `@XmlElement` va en los métodos get y no en los atributos, yo tengo un ejemplo así que si funciona:

```
@XmlElement    //nombre del tag xml
public String getPuesto() {
    return puesto;
}
```

Comment: Gracias. Eh probado de esa forma pero el problema sigue. Creo que el problema esta en separar los atributos de un tag a otra clase, no se si se especificara con alguna anotacion en especial, porque no me esta reconociendo.

Comment: Si agregas un clase dirección debe haber un tag dirección en el xml y sus hijos serán los atributos, y en la clase principal una propiedad dirección. Si no lo deseas así la clase dirección no debe existir y debes poner todo dentro de empleado. Si tienes la idea de separar dirección, lo que esta mal es el diseño de tu xml.

Comment: No conoces ninguna otra forma, sin tener que cambiar el xml? Es que lo recibo desde un webservice. Estuve leyendo sobre la creacion del binding con "xjc"..

Comment: La forma es que metas todos los atributos de dirección en la clase empleado como esta en el XML, y no inventes uno que se llame dirección.